# Understanding variables and functions in while loops

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables, while-loop

I have a function thar uses a while loop that goes like this

```
def fun_rightamount(monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r,errore=False):
    epsilon = 100
    num_guesses = 0 
    low = 0 
    high = 100
    portion_saved = (high + low)/2.0    
    while abs(fun_thirtysix(portion_saved,monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r) - down_payment ) >= epsilon : 
        if fun_thirtysix(portion_saved,monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r)  < down_payment  :             
            low = portion_saved        
        else: 
            high = portion_saved         
        portion_saved = (high + low)/2.0                
        num_guesses += 1 
        if portion_saved > 99.9999:            
            print('attenzione ERRORE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            errore=True
            break    
    return portion_saved,num_guesses,errore
```

I can change the while statment using another function   'pippo'

```
def pippo(portion_saved,monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r):
    yy=(fun_thirtysix(portion_saved,monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r) - down_payment) 
    return yy

def fun_rightamount(monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r,errore=False):
    epsilon = 100
    num_guesses = 0 
    low = 0 
    high = 100
    portion_saved = (high + low)/2.0    
    while abs(pippo(portion_saved,monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r)) >= epsilon :  #
        if pippo(portion_saved,monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r)  < 0  :           #  
            low = portion_saved                                                                  #
        else: 
            high = portion_saved         
        portion_saved = (high + low)/2.0                
        num_guesses += 1 
        if portion_saved > 99.9999:            
            print('attenzione ERRORE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            errore=True
            break    
    return portion_saved,num_guesses,errore
```

and everything works as expected,the two constructs works exavctly the same, but if I try to use a variable ('yy') in my while statement instead of a function my program enters an infinite loop:

```
def fun_rightamount(monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r,errore=False):
    epsilon = 100
    num_guesses = 0 
    low = 0 
    high = 100
    portion_saved = (high + low)/2.0
    yy=(fun_thirtysix(portion_saved,monthly_salary,down_payment,semi_annual_rise,r) - down_payment) # 
    while abs(yy) >= epsilon :                                                                      #
        if yy  < 0  :                                                                               #     
            low = portion_saved        
        else: 
            high = portion_saved         
        portion_saved = (high + low)/2.0                
        num_guesses += 1 
        if portion_saved > 99.9999:            
            print('attenzione ERRORE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            errore=True
            break    
    return portion_saved,num_guesses,errore
```

the while loop, loops but the num_guesses  incraeses, the abs(yy) values doesnt change and the portion_saved stays as '0' while at least in the first loop shoulb be '50'. Any idea ?

Comment: `yy` gets set once, when you assign it, and then never changes. Even if `portion_saved` would change, you'd need to run the function again and assign it to `yy` again. In your earlier example, you call the function on every iteration, so it terminates correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green Cloak Guy answered my question

yy gets set once, when you assign it, and then never changes. Even if portion_saved would change, you'd need to run the function again and assign it to yy again. In your earlier example, you call the function on every iteration, so it terminates correctly – Green Cloak Guy Apr 29 at 19:07